# Best way to map a triplet to an int in Java

Tags: java

I'd like to map Triplets to an Int, like so:

```
(12,6,6) -> 1
(1,0,6)  -> 1
(2,3,7)  -> 0
```

I need to be able access the Int and each individual values in the triplet.

What's the most efficient way of doing this in Java?

Thanks

Comment: Create a class `Triplet` with all information you need

Comment: ... or `Map<Triplet, Integer>`, `Triplet` MUST implement `equals` and `hashCode`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java has **no built-in** method for representing **tuples**.

But you can easily create one on your one. Just take a look at this simple generic `Triple` class:

```
public class Triple<A, B, C> {
    private final A mFirst;
    private final B mSecond;
    private final C mThird;

    public Triple(final A first, final B second, final C third) {
        this.mFirst = first;
        this.mSecond = second;
        this.mThird = third;
    }

    public A getFirst() {
        return this.mFirst;
    }

    public B getSecond() {
        return this.mSecond;
    }

    public C getThird() {
        return this.mThird;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + this.mFirst.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + this.mSecond.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + this.mThird.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Triple other = (Triple) obj;
        if (this.mFirst == null) {
            if (other.mFirst != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!this.mFirst.equals(other.mFirst)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.mSecond == null) {
            if (other.mSecond != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!this.mSecond.equals(other.mSecond)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.mThird == null) {
            if (other.mThird != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!this.mThird.equals(other.mThird)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The class just holds the three values and provides **getters**. Additionally it overrides `equals` and `hashCode` by comparing all three values.

Don't be scared of how `equals` and `hashCode` are implemented. They were generated by an **IDE** (most *IDE*s are capable of doing this).

---

You can then create your mappings using a `Map` like this:

```
Map<Triple<Integer, Integer, Integer>, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(new Triple<>(12, 6, 6), 1);
map.put(new Triple<>(1, 0, 6), 1);
map.put(new Triple<>(2, 3, 7), 0);
```

And access them by `Map#get`:

```
Triple<Integer, Integer, Integer> key = ...
int value = map.get(key);
```

Alternatively you could add a fourth value to your `Triple` class, like `id` or something like that. Or build a `Quadruple` class instead.

---

For convenience you could also create a generic factory method like `Triple#of` and add it to the `Triple` class:

```
public static <A, B, C> Triple<A, B, C> of(final A first,
        final B second, final C third) {
    return new Triple<>(first, second, third);
}
```

You can then use it to create instances of `Triple` slightly compacter. Compare both methods:

```
// Using constructor
new Triple<>(12, 6, 6);

// Using factory
Triple.of(12, 6, 6);
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer! I appreciate it. Just a question, how can I call a specific triplet? I've tried making the `key = <12, 6, 6> ` and `(12, 6, 6)`, but this doesnt seem to work. What should `key` contain?

Comment: @Johny You need to use the usual Java syntax for creating an instance of a new class. It will be `Triple<Integer, Integer, Integer> key = new Triple<>(12, 6, 6);` Alternatively you could create a factory method like `Triple#of`. I've edited the answer to also include this.

Comment: @Johny Remember that Java has no built-in syntax for triples and you also can't add it. You need to create explicit classes and instances of them instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Triple`

```
HashMap<Triple<Integer, Integer, Integer>, Integer> tripletMap = new HashMap<>();
tripletMap.put(Triple.of(12, 6, 6), 1);
```